# cannot read property type of in reducers in redux

Tags: react-native, redux

I am getting this error "cannot read property type of undefined" in reducers at places.js in the repository that I link here .I have actions and they are of different types so what is the reason for this ?
Here is the link to the repository 
[enter link description here](https://github.com/kolaveridi/PlacesApp)

Comment: Debug and check when reducer is called, how action is received. Print console response here

Answer (score 0):

Your actions will reach the reducers via the `dispatch` function which redux's `connect` will pass to your actions.

Instead of returning an object with `type` and `payload`, use `dispatch({ type, payload })` instead in your actions.

Your action should look like this

```
function actionName (args) {
    // any logic which you may need
    return (dispatch) {
        dispatch({ payload: 'payload data', type: 'yourType'})
    }
}
```